# How to get the number of partitions written by a DataFrameWriter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume we have the following code in Spark:

```
dataset.write.partitionBy("c1", "c2", "c3").parquet("myDir")
```

I have seen a couple of threads on SO explaining how to get the number of files or records written after the `parquet` method completes. However, what I would like to access is the name of the partitioning directories created, i.e. the number of directories `myDir/c1=XX/c2=YY/c3=ZZ` where XX, YY and ZZ are domain-related values.

One reason I need these directory names is to perform data integrity checks after an ETL process, and need to know which directories have been created during the ETL (say 3-4 directories for my use case) among thousands of them.

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve this information (at the Spark API level)?